# How can I view which app has the permission to turn on and off the location services in Android?

Tags: permissions, android-10, geolocation, location-services, samsung-galaxy-s-9

How can I view which app has the permission to turn on and off the location in Android? I use a Samsung Galaxy S9 phone with Android 10.

Comment: All apps with `android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS` can turn on / off the location.

Comment: @IrfanLatif thanks! How can I see which app have `android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS`?

Comment: You can use any app that shows the complete list of permissions of installed apps.

Answer (score 4):

As an answer to your [comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/249642#comment336067_249642), you can use [PermissionManagerX](https://github.com/mirfatif/PermissionManagerX). If your device isn't rooted, you can grant elevated privileges using ADB (instructions in app help). But elevated privileges are not required if you only want to see the list of permissions.

Search for `android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS` permission to get the list of apps:

[image]

To view also the system and framework apps, disable exclusion filters in drawer -> Exclusion Filters.

Answer (score 1):

try settings > privacy > manage permissions > location>

you should be displayed a list of the apps

Always allowed >
Allowed during the use>
Not allowed>

**I suggest you tick the three horizontal dots on up right side of the screen to display the system processes also**
and if if you don't know wtf that specific service is just make a search on google, that will keep you entertained for a while, it does for me hahah!

Comment: This answers *"which apps have the permission to **use** the location services"*, not *"which apps have the permission to **turn on and off** the location services"*.